# Getting a tangent line equation

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Suppose that $g$ is a differentiable function of two variables, and the equation $g(x,y)=7$ defines the curve $C$ in 2-space. Also suppose that $f$ is a differentiable function of two variables and $f(x,y)=-7$ for all $(x,y)$ on $C$. If the point $(a,b)$ satisfies $g(a,b)=7$ and $\nabla f(a,b)=(2,5)$. **Find an equation for the tangent line to $C$ at (a,b).**

My attempt is that assume that $f(x,y)=-g(x,y)$, then $f(x,y)=-7$ for all $(x,y)\in C$ is satiesfied. Then the vector perpendicular to line $C$ at $(a,b)$ is $(-2,-5)$, then the line equation tangent to it is : $\frac{y-b}{x-a}=\frac{-2}{5}$

Comment: You need not assume that $f=-g$ for all $(x,y)$.  The tangent line at $(a,b)$ is normal to $\nabla f=(2,5)$ and is therefore parallel to $(-5,2)$.  Then, your conclusion is correct.

Comment: @Dr.MV If I don't assume that, how can I know the direction of the tangent line, please give me more hint.

Comment: You are given that $f$ is constant on $C$ and therefore its gradient at a point on $C$ is normal to $C$ at that point.

Comment: @Dr.MV Yeah, your explanation is very clear, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.